# How to write API for insertion and erase functionality of multimap?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I am implementing a replacement container library which stores value of any type in some sorted manner, I need to write API in C++ to get the Sorted functionality by using equivalent boost functionality (multimap).

I am working in a project called RogueWave library replacement, and I need to implement functionality of `RWTValSortedVector` functionality using the Boost library. I need to write the API for this class using Boost library code.

These two things I needed to implement it in Boost.

1. `insert(const_reference a)`
2. `remove(const_reference a)`

The reference link for `RWTValSortedVector` is, https://docs.roguewave.com/sourcepro/11/html/toolsref/rwtvalsortedvector.html

I need this equivalent boost API for that functionality.

Here I mentioned my code snippet formats,

```
boost::container::multiset<data type, less<data_type> > vec;
vec.insert(data_type("value"));
vec.insert(data_type("value"));

//for erase method
vec.erase(data_type("value"));
```

I need to write container library API which stores value of any type in some sorted manner. Anyone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What is `vecval`? Why do you use a "multimap" where the mapped type is a comparison object? Where's your code for the replace container? You simply use `multimap` directly, which is obviously not a valid replacement. You need to write your own (and you probably want to use multiset under the hood). Also, do yourself a favor and stay away from vagueness like "in some sorted manner". That's clouding your thinking.

Comment: I corrected that spelling mistake(vecval), i am trying to write this on my own and i cant post the whole code, in code snippet data_type should take any data type, and less keyword will take care of comparison, specialization of std::less for any pointer type yields a strict total order.

Comment: You can't post the whole code, but you can't expect help with code that we cannot see. Right now I've posted my own suggestion, which arguably is "cheating" a lot more on your homework, because you get that part for free now - assuming you didn't already have it (correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking up the actual [documentation for remove](https://docs.roguewave.com/sourcepro/11/html/toolsref/rwtvalsortedvector.html#24C8Yq4q5pTmdjYcDboN9w):

> Removes the first element t in self such that the expression (t == a) is true and returns true. Returns false if there is no such element.

So, this would be a start:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d7816298882b39b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct SortedVec {
    boost::container::flat_multiset<T> _data;

    auto begin() const { return _data.begin(); }
    auto end()   const { return _data.end(); }

    bool insert(T value) {
        _data.emplace(std::move(value));
        return true;
    }

    auto erase(T const& key) {
        auto r = _data.equal_range(key);
        if (r.first == r.second)
            return false;

        _data.erase(r.first);
        return true;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    SortedVec<std::string> vec;

    vec.insert("zz");
    vec.insert("value");
    vec.insert("value");
    vec.insert("aa");

    std::cout << "Before erase:";
    for (auto& s : vec) std::cout << " " << std::quoted(s);

    assert(vec.erase("value"));
    std::cout << "\nAfter 1 erase:";
    for (auto& s : vec) std::cout << " " << std::quoted(s);

    assert(vec.erase("value"));
    std::cout << "\nAfter 2 erases:";
    for (auto& s : vec) std::cout << " " << std::quoted(s);

    assert(!vec.erase("value"));
}
```

Prints

```
Before erase: "aa" "value" "value" "zz"
After 1 erase: "aa" "value" "zz"
After 2 erases: "aa" "zz"
```

Comment: Thanks "sehe".  But i am getting error while compiling the code(library related) too long errors here there is limit for words so i mentioned only few,    stack.h:8: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘begin’ with no type
stack.h:8: error: storage class specified for ‘begin’
stack.h:9: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘end’ with no type
stack.h:9: error: storage class specified for ‘end’
stack.cpp:15: error: could not convert ‘((vec.SortedVec<T>::erase [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >](((const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<

Comment: My demos are _live_ so you don't have to guess (a) whether they compile (b) how to compile them.

Comment: And here's your 20 year's flashback again: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7fd31d8f2a5dc47